# Error while initializing app TypeError: parentVal.concat is not a function

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I created a fresh Nuxt.js project: `npx create-nuxt-app  project`

Then I launch the server: `cd project && npm run dev`
Till this point is all ok.

Now I want to install [nuxt-i18n](https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/setup.html): `npm i nuxt-i18n` and then I added it in nuxt.config.js:

```
modules: [
    ['nuxt-i18n', {
      // Options
    }]
```

I am getting the following error in the console of the development tools (with a page showing blank):

```
app.js:455 [nuxt] Error while initializing app TypeError: parentVal.concat is not a function
    at mergeHook (commons.app.js:11924)
    at mergeField (commons.app.js:12185)
    at mergeOptions (commons.app.js:12176)
    at Vue._init (commons.app.js:15301)
    at new Vue (commons.app.js:15419)
    at _callee5$ (app.js:1317)
    at tryCatch (commons.app.js:5854)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (commons.app.js:6088)
    at Generator.prototype.(:3000/anonymous function) [as next] (http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/commons.app.js:5906:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (commons.app.js:33)
```

What causes this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems due to a sub dependency issue from `vue-meta` used by `vue-i18n`
(see the open issue https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-i18n/issues/127)

as workaround, try to set the `seo` option at false :

```
// nuxt.config.js

['nuxt-i18n', {
  seo: false
}]
```

Comment: I tried that option before but it did not work. +1 for the effort though

Comment: correct, I just tried the "seo" option too. it doesn't work :-/  we have to waiting a fix from the module.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to vue-meta. [Vue-meta 1.5.5](https://github.com/declandewet/vue-meta/releases/tag/v1.5.5) was released that is fixed this issue.
So you can update it and it will fine